# How to search specific value in semicolon separated column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have values like (P12, I2) and I want to search them in semicolon-separated MySQL column name custom_column, which has values like `P%` or `P2` or `P2;I2` or `P%;I2`. (Yes, it should work with wildcard too.)

I tried as below in where clause.

```
WHERE 'P2' LIKE CONTACT(table2.custom_column, '%')
```

But it is not working.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Read ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) and fix your schema.

Comment: @stickybit I am not designing the table. I am just using the existing table from Magento 2 cloud.

Comment: Replace `;` with `,` and use FIND_IN_SET().

Comment: @Akina I tried this but after that it is not working with Wildcard search.

Comment: Wildcard search not needed. `WHERE FIND_IN_SET('P12', REPLACE(table2.custom_column, ';', ',')`

Comment: @Akina Then how can it work if custom_column has the value `P%` or `P%;I2`?

Comment: Your column stores PATTERNS in CSV format??? you're in a cesspool...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225670/discussion-between-rohit-kundale-and-akina).

Comment: @Akina Actually, the search should return value if table2.custom_column has any value as below `P%` or `P2` or `P2;I2` or `P%;I2`, Any suggestion?